# Meaning of ''in complexity'' in a sentence

Tags: word-meaning

I have read a sentence in an article.

> Robots are growing in complexity.

What does "growing in complexity" mean in this sentence?

Comment: It might help users to respond to your question if you can provide a little more detail/context to your question; think about providing a link to the article or providing a larger chunk of surrounding text to aid in understanding of this fragment.

Comment: Younger people grow in height. The rest of us grow in width (or waist size). :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the short sentence "grow in complexity" means its(the robots' system)complexity is increasing day by day. Or we can just understand it as a phrase "grow in", it means a kind of quality(complexity) increase.

For reference only.

Answer (score 1):

It means

> robots are becoming more complex over time

Early Robot (on the right)

[image: here]


Recent Robot

[image: here]